# Help starting Unity via Exceed on Demand

Tags: unity

I  am trying to connect to an Ubuntu 14.04 server with Unity installed Via Exceed on Demand client. While I can start kde sessions by running /usr/bin/startkde, I am unable to start Unity sessions by simply running "unity" or "compiz" . I can only see the mouse.

Any pointers will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3D composited desktop managers like Unity, Gnome 3 and KDE 5 are not supported by the current version of Exceed on Demand. A new application software from Opentext called TurboX supports 3D desktops. So, all users should upgrade to the new one. 
Details available [here](http://connectivity.opentext.com/customer-care/3D-desktop.aspx)

> Exceed (with Exceed 3D) does not work well with GNOME 3.8+ or other 3D
>   composited desktop environments. The session may fail to launch and
>   the connection will consume a large amount of network bandwidth. The
>   same problems affect all remote X servers.
>
> Exceed onDemand™ cannot launch GNOME 3.8+. This problem affects all X
>   servers based on older versions of the X.Org codebase.